# How to read from another terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal, c, read

I opened two terminals (/dev/pts/1 and /dev/pts/2) and started my application from /dev/pts/1. I want to read in real time from /dev/pts/2 but my code doesn't work: actually some of the symbols are shown on the /dev/pts/1 and some of them are shown on the /dev/pts/2

```
FILE *f = fopen("dev/pts/2", "r");
while(1) {
    char current = fgetc(f);
    printf("%c", current);
    fflush(0);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two processes reading from `/dev/pts/2`. One is the shell (or some application) running there, the other is your application on `pts/1`. It's random which one is faster reading the available bytes.

Comment: So I can do nothing?

Comment: Make sure noone else is reading from there. What's your ultimate goal?

Comment: If you want to have your app's input and output at two different terminals, it's easier to run the app on the terminal where you're about to type the input, and redirect the output to the other one.

Comment: I'm writing an application which reads lines from some files (in such order: first line from first file, first line from second file, ..., second line from first file etc.). Some files can be terminals so I have to read lines from them.

Comment: If you don't want the shell and your program competing for input, type `sleep 99999` to the shell.

Answer (score 0):

As @egmont said, in the terminal you type input (in your case, it is `/dev/pts/2`), the shell will read your input too. So, you should prevent the shell from reading it, and the program running in another terminal (in your case, it is `/dev/pts/1`) can read the input entirely.

You can launch a simple dead loop program which do not read from input at all in `/dev/pts/2`, which will prevent shell reading input. The complete source code of C language is simple as below, and yes you even needn't `#include<stdio.h>`

```
int main(){
    while(1);
}
```

Then you can launch the application in `/dev/pts/1`, the major part of source code is as you provided, and the complete source code is as below:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    FILE* fp=fopen("/dev/pts/2","r");
    while(1){
        char c=fgetc(fp);
        if(c==-1)break;
        fputc(c,stdout);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that you should launch dead loop **before** the other program, also note that you should enter your input from `/dev/pts/2` **while the dead loop program is running**. In addition, only when you press `Enter`, will the application in `/dev/pts/1` get the input, and the `newline` character will be read too.

And when you run these two programs, the two terminals look like below, in `/dev/pts/2`:

```
$ ./dead_loop
abc
d
```

and in `/dev/pts/1`:

```
$ ./my_application
abc
d
```